# Cannot import tweepy after it has been installed

Tags: python, python-3.10

I installed tweepy through CMD by using the 'pip install tweepy' command. However, when I import it in my code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Code\twitter code\pfp_changer.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy'
```

Furthermore, this command outputs a list that does not include tweepy.

```
help("modules")
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am using python version 3.10.0.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What happens if you do a ```pip freeze```?

Comment: Is the `pip` binary you're using associated with the `python` binary you're using? If not, there's your problem.

Comment: I have pretty much the same problem , I've found out where tweepy package is supposed to be installed on my computer and there's many .py files inside that can be opened as modules but there doesn't appear to be any tweepy.py file that I can see

Comment: This response is a day later , I found something that works for me, I found out where the tweepy/OAuth and  distro info ecr were were installed by typing "pip install tweepy" in the command prompt on windows then when to that folder and copied all those files and pasted them to the "Lib/site-packages" folder in my main python files path. Still didn't find a tweepy.py file/module but everything works fine now :P

Answer (score 1):

firstly, you need to check your PATH and see if you have duplicated python versions, if yes, try deleting one and install into the other
if no:

try installing tweepy in cmd like this:

```
python -m pip install tweepy
```